# Why doesn't sign-in page load properly on time in my Next.js project?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, netlify, next-auth

I'm not really sure whats wrong with my algorithm that i wrote in signin.js route API in next.js e-commerce project but it was woroking fine to get that page load right on time, without making wait long time(around 1s), but the things just changed as soon as i deployed in netlify, and error page of netlify pops out saying `"2023-04-09T13:26:17.617Z 4cba366e-5bdf-4bcc-b6f0-9d6975604105 Task timed out after 10.02 seconds"`

I have run out all my options, spent days trying to fix it, and tried numerous suggested solutions around the net, but none of them have worked so far, and now feeling really so hopeless. Same thing also happens when i deploy in AWS Amplify, moreover my images dont even show up there, saw that some guys suggested on github to ask netlify to increase the timeout limit, but i dont think this is gonna sort out the issue since visitors wont wait more than 4 seconds for that pages to load, i cant even tell how desperate im right now, spent so much time developing this project and need to showcase in my github for my customer soon, any help is endless appreciated.

P.S: something similar also happens in **forgot.js** page, always returning 500 or 502 when i typed the email though it exists in my ddatabase!
**whats i have tried so far:**

-switched to different cloud platforms like Amplify, Vercel...

-checked many times if there was something wrong in .env file, im pretty sure its all ok and  doubled checked each variable out there.

-updated all packages in the project, also reinstalled node_modules

**production link:** https://musical-lokum-78f90a.netlify.app/

**pages >signin.js**

```
import React from "react";

import styles from "../styles/signin.module.scss";
import { BiLeftArrowAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import Link from "next/link";

import LoginInput from "../components/custom/loginIput";
import Image from "next/image";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useState } from "react";

import { getProviders } from "next-auth/react";

import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import BarLoader from "react-spinners/BarLoader";
import {getCsrfToken} from 'next-auth/react'


function Signin({ providers, csrfToken, callbackUrl }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const router = useRouter();

  const [message, setMessage] = useState({
    error: "",
    successMessage: "",
  });

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  
 

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
    });

    if (result?.error) {
      setLoading(false);
      setMessage({ ...message, error: result.error });
    }

    if (result?.ok) {
      const session = await getSession();
      console.log(session);
      const successMessage = "You have successfully logged in !";
      const waitTime = 3000;
      setLoading(false);

      setMessage({ ...message, successMessage });

      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
        router.push(callbackUrl || "/");
      }, waitTime);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
   
  };

  return (
    <>
     

      <div className={styles.login}>
        <div className={styles.login__container}>
          <div className={styles.login__header}>
            <div className={styles.goback__svg}>
              <BiLeftArrowAlt />
            </div>

            <span>Shop over +1 million products !</span>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.login__form}>
            <Image src="/profilelogo.svg" width={100} height={100} alt="not" />
            <h3>Sign in</h3>
            <p> Sign in and start shopping immediately !</p>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <LoginInput
                icon="user"
                placeholder="Username"
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="text"
                name="email"
                value={user.email}
                required={true}
              />
              <LoginInput
                icon="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                onChange={handleChange}
                type="password"
                name="password"
                value={user.password}
                required={true}
              />
              {message.error && (
                <div
                  className={styles.login__error}
                  onAnimationEnd={() => setMessage({ ...message, error: "" })}
                  key={message.error}
                >
                  <p>{message.error}</p>
                </div>
              )}

              {message.successMessage && (
                <div
                  className={styles.login__success}
                  onAnimationEnd={() =>
                    setMessage({ ...message, successMessage: "" })
                  }
                  key={message.successMessage}
                >
                  <p>{message.successMessage}</p>
                </div>
              )}

              <div className={styles.links}>
                <span>
                  <Link className={styles.links__span__a} href="/signup">
                    Create an account
                  </Link>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <Link
                    className={styles.links__span__a}
                    href="auth/forgot"
                  >
                    Forgot password
                  </Link>
                </span>
              </div>

              <button className={styles.loginButton} type="submit">
                {
                  loading ? <BarLoader
                  color="#fff"
                  height={5}
                  loading = {loading}
                  speedMultiplier={2}
                  width={100}
                />
                : "Sign in"
                }

              </button>

              <div className={styles.divider}>
                <span>or</span>
              </div>
              { providers &&
                Object.values(providers).map((item, index) =>
                item.id === "credentials" ? null : (
                  <div className={styles.login__social} key={index}>
                    <a onClick={() => signIn(item.id)}>
                      <Image
                        src={`/${item.id}.svg`}
                        width={20}
                        height={20}
                        alt={`${item.name}`}
                      />
                      <span>Continue with {`${item.name}`}</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                )
              )}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  );
}

export default Signin;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req, query } = context;
  const providers = await getProviders();

  const session = await getSession({ req });

  const csrfToken = await getCsrfToken(context);
  const { callbackUrl } = query;

  let defaultCallbackUrl = "/";

  if (callbackUrl) {
    defaultCallbackUrl = callbackUrl;
  }

  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: defaultCallbackUrl,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { providers, session, csrfToken, callbackUrl: defaultCallbackUrl },
  };
}
```

**pages/api/auth> [...nextauth].js**

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import User from '../../../models/User'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import joi from 'joi'
import {connectDB, disconnect} from '../../../utils/db'
import {MongoDBAdapter} from '@next-auth/mongodb-adapter'
import clientPromise from './lib/mongodb'

import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt'


dotenv.config()


 const loginSchema = joi.object({
  email: joi.string().email().required(),
  password: joi.string().min(6).required(),

});



export default NextAuth({
     adapter : MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'credentials',
     name : 'Sign in',
      credentials : {
        email: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "********" }
      },

      async authorize(credentials,req) {

        try {

         await connectDB()

        const email = credentials.email
        const password = credentials.password
        console.log(email,password)

        if (!email || !password) {
          throw new Error('Please provide an email and password.');
        }

        const {error} = loginSchema.validate({email,password})
        if (error) {
          throw new Error(error.details[0].message);
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({email})

        if (!user) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password.');
        }

        const checkMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

        if (!checkMatch) {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password.');
        }




        return user
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);

      }

      finally
      {
        await disconnect()
        
        
      }
    
      }
      
      }),
 
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret:process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,

    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: "Iv1.2a94b24ea5010c98",
      clientSecret: "71ff167e340484f06b9e03ff73bb64e4e667f8cb",
    }),
    
  
  ],

  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
  },

  callbacks: {
    async session({session, token}) {
    
      
      let user = await User.findById(token.sub);
     
      session.user.id = token.sub || user?._id?.toString();
      session.user.role = user?.role || 'user';      
      return session;
    }
  },

 

    session: {
     
    strategy: 'jwt',


    },
    jwt: {
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,

    },
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,




})
```

**error message:**

[image]

[image]

**.env file:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind there is `Functions` settings under `Project Settings` on Vercel dashboard and on that settings you can set the `Edge Function` region. If you have a db in Frankfurt and you set the function region in San Fransisco, you will naturally have delays.

Make sure that your edge functions run as close to your db as possible.